# Git flow feature in branch on stage server

Tags: features

I am testing out a git feature and pushed the branch to the staging server to show the client.
Because it is a drupal feature, I think I need to revert the feature on the branch on the stage server.

My question is if I am in feature/branch and I revert the drupal feature to allow the updates to show up. When I checkout develop will that whipe away the revert I did on the feature/branch?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch from the feature branch back to develop, it won't wipe them out because the changes are stored in the database, and you should see an **overridden** status on the feature. Once you switch back to develop, you can perform a feature-revert again to change the settings back.

Either way, I would backup the database, either using Backup & Migrate, or directly on the server, just in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: Kyle, Thanks! That is what I needed to know to move forward.